# Node.js serial port Access denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I really need your help
I'm trying to make a program with node.js to act as a server for mobile app HTTP requests,and in this code in i'm trying to send a String on the Serial Port (to an Arduino).
it gives me this error :

`
Server running at http://192.168.1.116:3000/
Open
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Opening COM2: Access denied
    at Error (native)`

This s my code :

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '192.168.1.116';
const portserver = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var serialPort = new SerialPort('COM2', {baudrate: 9600});
serialPort.on ('open', function () {
console.log("Open");
serialPort.write(0x05);

});
res.end('Hello')
});

server.listen(portserver, hostname, () => {
 console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${portserver}/`);
 });
```

Comment: This isn't an issue with your code, it's with permissions on the serial port device.  Provide information about your OS, or just Google about permissions on serial devices for your OS.

Comment: it gives me the access just for the first request,,after that the error is displayed and the server (node.js) stops

Comment: I tried to close the port after closing the request but it gives the same issue